# Old Windows XP EXE program can´t run on Windows server 2019 standard

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2019

I´m moving an old exe program from Windows XP(Service Pack 2) to a Windows server 2019 standard. The program runs fine on my Windows 10 developer machine, but when I try to run the program on the Windows server 2019, the program crashes and gives the following output in the Evenlog:

[image]
[image]

[image]

**I have tried the following**

- Installed .NET SDK
- Tried to run the program in different combability modes
- Installed Visual Studio with alle the packages that might be related to the issue(C++, .Net development and so on)
- Created a Windows 8.1 server on Hyper-V and tested the EXE program and it runs just fine.
- Tried to run the program from the windows 32-bit emulator(C:\Windows\SysWOW64)

It´s an old program, am I missing a specifik .NET package ?

Comment: What is on the Win 10 developer machine that is not on the other one?

Comment: Allot of SDK versions and so on. But the problem is the a plain machine with windows 8.1 and no additional packages can run the program out of the box.

Comment: I have made some process. I have made a copy of the program to the SysWOW64 folder. Now the program starts but crashes again when given an input parameter to a file in it´s current folder. After the crash the program has written in it´s internal log:
´>Allegro CL for Windows Exception Report 04/09/23 22:05:46.
  ACL Kernel version: 3.0.7
  Execution address = 0x02686380: Invalid Write Access to 0x02686380
--Backtrace for exception
  fp=0019fd94 resume @=00000000: lisp frame: INTERPRETER
  fp=0019fda0 resume @=00000000: base frame
== backtrace chain broken (00000000)
== end backtrace´

Comment: I have also added a picture of the error to the question (Aclxdump.txt)